# How to download all links from a ftp link?

Tags: python, ftp, urllib

Is there a way to download all files from a ftp link, preferably not overwriting if same file already exists in download folder? I can download specific links like this:

```
import urllib 

urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://server/path/to/file', 'file')
```

Comment: What do you mean, "links"? FTP doesn't have links.

Comment: If you are trying to connect to an FTP server, maybe you should also use something that is more FTP-friendly in Python? There *is* [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) available to you out-of-the-box.

Comment: thanks @DanielRoseman, I mean all files on a ftp page.

Comment: @idjaw, I am open to FTPlib, but does it allow to download all files on the server?

Comment: You can use `wget` from the command-line to fetch via ftp if python is not a requirement for the task. Note that ftp does not support the `*` and you must use a flag to `wget`.

Comment: @user308827 Have you read the documentation and played around with it to see if it would help you? I suggest you dive in and play around. Think of it like a nice big sandbox. :)

Comment: thanks @idjaw, that is a fair comment. I do have a working prototype to get one file from the ftp server at a time

Comment: There's nothing like "ftp page". Maybe you mean all files in a directory on FTP server?